# Airflow scheduler can not connect to Kubernetes service api

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to setup airflow with Kubernetes executor and on scheduler container startup it hangs for a while and then I get https timeout error as follows. The ip address in message is correct and inside container I can run `curl kubernetes:443` or `curl 10.96.0.1:443` or `nc -zv 10.96.0.1 443` so I assume there is no firewall or so blocking access.

I am using local kubernetes as well as aws EKS but same error, I can see that ip changes in different clusters.

I have looked at google to find a solution but did not see similar cases.

```
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/executors/kubernetes_executor.py", line 335, in run                                                                                                                                                                                                                               │
│     self.worker_uuid, self.kube_config)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/executors/kubernetes_executor.py", line 359, in _run                                                                                                                                                                                                                              │
│     **kwargs):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 144, in stream                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   │
│     for line in iter_resp_lines(resp):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 48, in iter_resp_lines                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           │
│     for seg in resp.read_chunked(decode_content=False):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 781, in read_chunked                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   │
│     self._original_response.close()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            │
│     self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       │
│   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 430, in _error_catcher                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 │
│     raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  │
│ urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.96.0.1', port=443): Read timed out.
```

**update**: I found my problem, but no solution yet. 
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/990

Comment: Are you using HELM charts to setup in kubernetes? The log provided is from a k8's container? Please provide more details about the implementation and I will try to help you with you setup.

Comment: @rabello yes i am using helm3, log is from scheduler deployment pod. code is modified version of this repo: https://github.com/duy0611/airflow-eks-helm-demo/

Comment: I've installed Airflow in GKE using Helm3 [bitnami/airflow](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-airflow) and everything is running fine. Have some special reason for you use this version?

Comment: I also isolated problem to kubernetes python client too. so still can not understand why it does not happen for other people. it is something about timeouts.

Comment: I am having same issue with airflow `v1.10.8` did you figure out how to fix this?

Comment: @AsavPatel add the timeout parameter in answer below, then you will continue to see error in every 50 seconds but scheduler will work in other threads and your dags will run. At least that's how it is for me now. But I don't understand why this is ignored in kubernetes python client. (PS; do not forget to put a dag into dags folder, example dags do NOT work for me)

Comment: I am using helm chart (stable/airflow) and building `puckle/docker-airflow` image with kubernetes enabled. after adding that environment variable I get ```self.kube_client_request_args = json.loads(kube_client_request_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)``` from airflow-scheduler

Comment: @AsavPatel I wrote that parameter values is like this, `kube_client_request_args = {"_request_timeout" : [60,60]}` not getting that error anymore. This line is in a file in configmap definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to set the value via the ENV variable. In your charts/airflow.yaml file, you can set the variable as follows and that should solve your problem,

```
AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__KUBE_CLIENT_REQUEST_ARGS: {"_request_timeout" : [50, 50]}
```

- PR Reference: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/6643
- Problem Discussion: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-6040

airflow.yaml full code

```
airflow:
  image:
     repository: airflow-docker-local
     tag: 1
  executor: Kubernetes
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
  config:
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:airflow@airflow-postgresql:5432/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://postgres:airflow@airflow-postgresql:5432/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:airflow@airflow-redis-master:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOGGING: True
    AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID: my_s3_connection
    AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER: s3://xxx-airflow/logs
    AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__LOG_FETCH_TIMEOUT_SEC: 25
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: True
    AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__EXPOSE_CONFIG: True
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: -xyz=
    AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_CONTAINER_REPOSITORY: airflow-docker-local
    AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_CONTAINER_TAG: 1
    AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_CONTAINER_IMAGE_PULL_POLICY: Never
    AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME: airflow
    AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DAGS_VOLUME_CLAIM: airflow
    AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__NAMESPACE: airflow
    AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__KUBE_CLIENT_REQUEST_ARGS: {"_request_timeout" : [50, 50]}


persistence:
  enabled: true
  existingClaim: ''

workers:
  enabled: true

postgresql:
  enabled: true

redis:
  enabled: true
```

Comment: I did that and request_timeout was not enough, I also added timeout parameter. but this is not only related to airflow, I have sample code using only kubernetes python library, client, watch and filtering on pod tag does not work without timeout parameter.